# .NET service responds 500 internal error and "missing parameter" to HttpWebRequest POSTS but test form works fine

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, httpwebrequest, asmx

I am using a simple .NET service (asmx) that works fine when invoking via the test form (POST).  When invoking via a HttpWebRequest object, I get a WebException "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."  Digging deeper, reading the WebException.Response.GetResponseStream() I get the message: "Missing parameter: serviceType." but I've clearly included this parameter.

I'm at a loss here, and its worse that I don't have access to debug the service itself.

Here is the code being used to make the request:

```
string postData = String.Format("serviceType={0}&SaleID={1}&Zip={2}", request.service, request.saleId, request.postalCode);
byte[] data = (new ASCIIEncoding()).GetBytes(postData);

HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpWebRequest.Timeout = 60000;
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWebRequest.ContentLength =  data.Length;

using (Stream newStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

try
{
    using (response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            throw new Exception("There was an error with the shipping freight service.");

        string responseData;
        using (StreamReader responseStream = new      StreamReader(httpWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(),    System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
        {
            responseData = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
            responseStream.Close();
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseData))
            throw new Exception("There was an error with the shipping freight service.  Request went through but response is empty.");

        XmlDocument providerResponse = new XmlDocument();
        providerResponse.LoadXml(responseData);

        return providerResponse;
    }
}
catch (WebException webExp)
{
    string exMessage = webExp.Message;

    if (webExp.Response != null)
    {
        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webExp.Response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            exMessage = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    throw new Exception(exMessage);
}
```

Anyone have an idea what could be happening?

Thanks.

UPDATE

Stepping through the debugger, I see the parameters are correct.  I also see the parameters are correct in fiddler.

Examining fiddler, I get 2 requests each time this code executes.  The first request is a post that sends the parameters.  It gets a 301 response code with a "Document Moved Object Moved This document may be found here" message.  The second request is a GET to the same URL with no body.  It gets a 500 server error with "Missing parameter: serviceType." message.

Comment: Everything looks ok as far as building the web request goes. I guess the obvious question is, "Are you sure `request.service` isn't null or an invalid value when you build your postData?"

Comment: Run Fiddler in the background and capture the request/response to verify that the request sent is valid.

Comment: Yes, I step through the debugger in visual studio.  Also have looked at fidler...all looks good.

Comment: Take a look at my tutorial and compare your code to mine, maybe you will spot something http://netpl.blogspot.com/2007/05/klient-webservices.html?m=0

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you found your problem when you looked at the requests in Fiddler. Taking an excerpt from http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html:

> **10.3.2 301 Moved Permanently**
>
> The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the returned URIs. Clients with link editing capabilities ought to automatically re-link references to the Request-URI to one or more of the new references returned by the server, where possible.
>
> .....
>
> *Note: When automatically redirecting a POST request after
>         receiving a 301 status code, some existing HTTP/1.0 user agents
>         will erroneously change it into a GET request.*

Here's a couple options that you can take:

1. Hard-code your program to use the new Url that you see in the 301 response in Fiddler
2. Adjust your code to retrieve the 301 response, parse out the new Url from the response, and build a new response with the new Url.

The latter option would be ideal if you're dealing with user-based input on the Url (like a web browser), since you don't know where the user is going to want your program to go.

Comment: 1/2. The 301 redirect is to the SAME url.  Since the second request is an automatic thing by the .NET runtime, I just think this is how the .NET runtime works for asmx services or for handling errors, but I may be wrong.  The redirect is not the issue, the fact that the above code gets a response with an erroneous 'missing parameter' message is the issue.  The service is a standard .NET asmx service.  The above code is boilerplate POST request in C#.

Comment: @IanHerbert The last thing I can think of is perhaps some missing headers in your request is causing the service to throw an error. Really though, your first code that you posted should have worked out fine (and you already know that). If you've already replicated the web form request character-for-character in your HttpWebRequest and it still doesn't work, then the last thing to look at is the service itself (which you already said wasn't possible). That's about where I'm at for ideas.

Comment: Yeah, I think unless I can gain access to the service I won't be able to do much more useful debugging.  Thanks.